# Compare (< or >) the result of one column, against the result of another column of two select statements? - Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

### Question:

How do you compare (< or >) the result of one column, against the result of another column of two select statements?

### More details:

I need to get a list only of the sold out movies. To do this, I need to check if
the number on the rented_movie_count on the first select statement is equal or greater than the number on the available_movie_count on the second select statement.

**First Statement**

```
result of the 
select MOVIE_ID, count(MOVIE_ID) as rented_movies_count
from MOVIE_QUEUE
WHERE STATUS_ID=2
group by MOVIE_ID;
```

**Second  Statement**

```
select MOVIE_ID, count(MOVIE_ID) as available_movie_count
from dvd
group by MOVIE_ID;
```

I am still very new to this and I am trying to learn, even suggestions about what kind of 
syntax (operators, expressions, etc) should I use will help at least point me on a a directions to do more research. Thanks in advance

Comment: **I just figure it out!!**I created 2 views out of each select statement and then join them with a > condition... anyways... suggestions are still accepted... I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your database structure, a possible solution would be

```
SELECT rented.MOVIE_ID
      ,rented_movies_count
      ,available_movie_count
  FROM (
        SELECT MOVIE_ID, count(MOVIE_ID) AS rented_movies_count
          FROM MOVIE_QUEUE
         WHERE STATUS_ID=2
        GROUP BY MOVIE_ID
       ) rented
     ,(SELECT MOVIE_ID, count(MOVIE_ID) AS available_movie_count
         FROM dvd
       GROUP BY MOVIE_ID
      ) available
 WHERE rented.movie_id = available.movie_id
   AND rented_movies_count >= available_movie_count 
;
```

I've set up an example on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fc59/11 to test. But I guess that's more or less what you've come up with.

But I somewhat doubt that your database structure is really optimal!? Do you really store more than one record for a singe `movie_id` in the table `dvd`?

Wouldn't it be more useful to have exactly one record per `movie_id` in `dvd` along with some movie attributes and store the rental status of the dvds in `movie_queue.status_id`?

If `movie_queue.status_id` is defined as say

1. ...available
2. ...rented

Then your query would be much more easy:

```
SELECT MOVIE_ID
      ,count(case when status_id = 1 then 1 end) AS available_movie_count
      ,count(case when status_id = 2 then 1 end) AS rented_movies_count
  FROM MOVIE_QUEUE
 GROUP BY MOVIE_ID
HAVING count(case when status_id = 2 then 1 end) >= count(case when status_id = 1 then 1 end)
;
```

See for example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13739/1

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, It works!. I do need to have more than one record for a singe movie_id in the table dvd because there is more than 1 dvd with the same movie title. Now I know only movies 1, 2 and 5 are sold out!

Comment: To get the movie_name, I tried this, but it did not give me the result I wanted:

SELECT 
       movie.movie_name,
       
  FROM (
        SELECT MOVIE_ID, count(MOVIE_ID) AS rented_movies_count
          FROM MOVIE_QUEUE
         WHERE STATUS_ID=2
        GROUP BY MOVIE_ID
       ) rented
     ,(SELECT MOVIE_ID, count(MOVIE_ID) AS available_movie_count
         FROM dvd
       GROUP BY MOVIE_ID
      ) available,
      movie
 WHERE rented.movie_id = available.movie_id
   AND rented_movies_count >= available_movie_count 
;

**Any Suggestions? Thanks again!***

Comment: Probably you need to join table movie with "available.movie_id = movie.movie_id", too. If this is answered for you, please accept the answer so that others know this is an answered question.